# jQuery .after() not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

I am trying to add a table row to a table using `.after()` but it's not working in any IE, I keep getting this error `"Object required"` and the error seems to be coming from line 5151 in my jQuery library.

Here is my code:

```
$('#view').live('click',function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.after("<tr><td>Test</td></tr>"); 
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `$(this).parent()` returns what you expect?

Comment: When I console.log it I get `object Object`, but this works in FF and Chrome, just not any of the IE's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A likely reason is that the HTML code isn't valid without a table tag.

Create the elements as separate elements instead:

```
parent.after($('<tr/>').append($('<td/>').text('Test')));
```

Comment: That does seem to add the text in underneath the tr, but I have to add two rows, not just the one, with about 10 columns in each row, all wrapped up in a table if possible. So I doubt that would work very well with this method. I would be happy to post the other code if you wouldn't mind having a look at that?

Comment: @user270311: That would work very well with this method. The methods chain, so you can just keep appending cells to the row. Alternatively you can create the row element and add cells to it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely validate your HTML first; this kind of thing often fails beacuse IE is less "generous" when things aren't valid.

Do you know what parent is? is it definitely a `tr`?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in IE, FF and Chrome: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dKzK8/).

Comment: JSFiddle no longer supported in IE lol. .After does not work in IE but does in Edge